# How to determine if a sequence is finite or infinite?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit

I have a C# exercise in which I have some trouble understanding how to complete it correctly, even after doing some research online.

So, basically, I have to write an Extension Method, called Smooth, which takes as arguments an infinite double sequence and a single integer. The method needs to produce an infinite double sequence, which is the result of the average number between the number in the same position (i), i-N and I+N. At the beginning, it should take the numbers 0 to N*2. For example, if N is 3, the result is expected to be:

avg(s0, ..., s3), avg(s0, ..., s4), avg(s0, ..., s5), avg(s0, ..., s6), avg(s1, ..., s7), avg(s2, ..., s8) and so on.

---

I think I have resolved this part, the problem is that I have to check if the source if finite. For example, if s = 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 it should throw an error before even start to count the first averages.

My take on the exercise is as seen below:

```
public static class SmoothExtensionMethod
{
    public static IEnumerable<double> Smooth(this IEnumerable<double> source, int N)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (N < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (source.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1) == 0.0)
            {
                // The idea is to check if the next number exists
                // to evaluate if the list is finite or infinite.
                throw new FiniteSourceException();
            }
        }
        
        return Smooth_real(source, N);
        
    }
    
    private static IEnumerable<double> Smooth_real(IEnumerable<double> source, int N)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i <= N)
            {
                yield return source.Take(N + i).Average();
            }

            else
            {
                var minRange = i - N;
                var maxRange = i + N;
                yield return source.ToList().GetRange(minRange, maxRange).Average();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also made the tests:

```
        [Test]
    public void Test1_FiniteSequence_Exception()
    {
        var source = new List<double>() { 42.0, 49.0, 47.0, 18.0, 19.0, 28.0, 26.0 };
        var N = 2;
        
        Assert.That(() => source.Smooth(N), Throws.TypeOf<FiniteSourceException>());
    }

    private IEnumerable<double> Aux1_Test3_sourceGen(double[] sourceSample)
    {
        int index = 0;
        int maxIndex = sourceSample.Count() - 1;
        
        for (;;)
        {
            yield return sourceSample.ElementAt(index);
            index += (index < maxIndex) ? 1 : -maxIndex;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<double> Aux2_Test3_outputGen(double[] expectedSample, int N)
    {
        int index = 0;
        int maxIndex = expectedSample.Count() - 1;

        for (;;)
        {
            yield return expectedSample.ElementAt(index);
            index += (index < maxIndex) ? 1 : -(N+1);
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test3_Parametric_ExpectedResult(
        [Random(2, 7, 3)] int N,
        [Values(new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 })] double[] sourceSample,
        [Values(new double[] { 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0 })] double[] expectedSample,
        [Values(5, 10, 15, 20, 100, 500)] int howMany)
    {
        var source = Aux1_Test3_sourceGen(sourceSample).Take(1000);
        var expectedOutput = Aux2_Test3_outputGen(expectedSample, N).Take(1000);
        
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedOutput.Take(howMany), source.Smooth(N));
    }
```

Please ignore the values on the test which I have written without any logic behind. Test1 should return an Exception, but Test3 should return the expected values.

Test1 is correctly evaluated but Test3 always fails with a FiniteSourceException instead of the expected result.

---

From what I have understood, I can't make a method with a infinite yield return without blocking it in any way. So I have used ".Take" to take a large number while the method can still generate a "infinite" list. But, if the parameters are in fact finite this way, the exception is always thrown (and I can't even throw exceptions in the "real" method because for some reason with a yield the throws are ignored).
How can I evaluate correctly those two tests, and determine if the sequence is in fact finite or infinite?
I'm quite sure I'm missing something here.

Sorry for the long post and the mistakes in my grammar (I have roughly translated the text from another language) and thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I'm having trouble to implement the FiniteSourceException as described in the original post, or, in other words, to check if the sequence "source" of the method Source is finite or infinite. So basically how can I implement this check and make the two tests successful?

Comment: I don't think you can check this "before even start to count the first averages". Rather than using LINQ, use a regular foreach loop to do the averages. After the loop, you throw the exception.

Comment: How are you going to differentiate between an infinite sequence and a sequence of 10^10^10^10^10^10 values? Enumerating all those values would take longer than the Universe has existed...

Comment: To iterate over an `IEnumerable`, use a `foreach`.  Don't iterate the *entire sequence* to get the count, then iterate the first item to get it, then the first two items to get the second, then the first three items to get the third, etc. to iterating N items to get the Nth item.  Just iterate it *once*.  It's all the more important when you have infinite sequence, and therefore counting them all is literally impossible.  It's *extremely* rare for it to ever be correct to use `ElementAt`, and you should generaly only be using `Count` *if you're not using anything else* on that sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t possible. There is no way to find that out. Turing defined that.

From just reading the question itself, what you could do is make a counter variable:

```
Int counter = 0;
```

Every time the code loop runs, the counter will increase (simple example):

```
while (1 == 1)
 {
     counter = counter + 1;
     Console.WriteLine(“greer”);
 }
```

Once the counter reaches a very big number, e.g four hundred billion, you could just stop the program and say that it will repeat forever.

```
while (1 == 1)
 {
     counter = counter + 1;
     Console.WriteLine(“greer”);
     if (counter == very large number)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(“program will loop”);
     }
 }
```

After a very long number of times the code has run, the program will decide that the program will loop. Although this would be a good way to figure the problem out, there could be a program that would stop at four hundred and one billion times, and you wouldn’t be able to know. Like said, Turing said that no computer would be able to solve this problem.

Thank you for reading my small brain answer.

Comment: "Turing said that no computer would be able to solve this problem" -- no, he just said his machine can't prove that. It just so happens that current day computers (except quantum computers) are all Turing Machines, but that is not necessarily always going to be the case.